# Adding 30 days, 60 days and 90 days column for payments made during that time in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to add three columns to my GridControl that shows payments made in the past 30, 60 and 90 days.
Below is my SQL statement that I use to get all the payments (Amount) that was made by a single customer.

```
SELECT p.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, SUM(p.Amount) As 'Amount
FROM Payment p
INNER JOIN Customer c
on p.CustomerID = c.ID
Group by p.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName
```

I have also tried the following but it only gives me a NULL value

```
SELECT p.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, SUM(p.Amount) As 'Amount', a.[30Days] As '30 Days'
FROM Payment p
inner join Customer c
on p.CustomerID = c.ID
JOIN (SELECT SUM(p.Amount) AS '30Days'
      FROM Payment p 
      WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), PaymentDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 30) AS a ON c.ID = p.CustomerID
Group by p.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, a.[30Days]
```

Comment: Do you have a column that you can use to calculate number of days?

Comment: You need to add a column to capture the date and time that payment was done.So that you can use the date diff to get the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should review datediff - you have the parameters the wrong way round, and you can use conditional aggregation so a third join is not required.

```
SELECT p.CustomerID,  SUM(p.Amount) As 'Amount',
         sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,  PaymentDate,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 then amount else 0 end) [30days],
         sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,  PaymentDate,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 60 then amount else 0 end) [60days],
         sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,  PaymentDate,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 then amount else 0 end) [90days]
FROM Payment p
INNER JOIN Customer c
on p.CustomerID = c.customerID
Group by p.CustomerID;
```